# Increase loop speed for FFT

Tags: r, time-series, frequency

I have heard that writing for loops in R is particularly slow. I have the following code which needs to run through 122,000 rows with each having 513 columns and transform them using `fft()` function:

```
for (i in 2:100000){
   Data1[i,2:513]<- fft(as.numeric(Data1[i,2:513]), inverse = TRUE)/512
}
```

I have tried to do this for 1000 cycles and that took few minutes... is there a way to do this loop faster? Maybe by not using a loop or by doing it in C?

Comment: You might be better on R-help or StackOverflow. What you have heard is not true by the way but this is off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks @mdewey, will post it there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mvfft` (documented on the `fft` help page) was designed to do this all at once.  It's hard to imagine how you could do it any faster: less than three seconds (on an older Xeon workstation) for a dataset exactly your size.

```
n.row <- 122e3
X <- matrix(rnorm(n.row*512), n.row)
system.time(
  Y <- mvfft(t(X), inverse=TRUE)/512
)
```

> user  system elapsed
>
> 2.34    0.39    2.75

Note that the discrete FFT in this case has complex values.

---

FFTs are *fast*.  Typically they can be computed in less time than it takes to read data from an ASCII file (because the character-to-numeric conversions involved in the read take more time than the calculations in the FFT).  Your limiting resources therefore are I/O throughput speed and RAM.  But 122,000 vectors of 512 complex values occupy "only" about a gigabyte, so you should be ok.